# Merge repeated variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var some1 = false;
var some2 = false;
var some3 = false;
var some4 = null;
var some5 = null;
var some6 = null;
```

Is it possible to merge variables by comma?

What is a true way to do this in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can in JS. You can only do something like this:

```
var some1 = false, some2 = false, some3 = false, some4 = null, some5 = null, some6 = null;
```

Comment: Good answer. That would be more readable with line breaks after the commas.

Comment: @Rooney It's possible and preferred, if all your variable values are the same.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
var some1 = some2 = some3 = false;
var some4 = some5 = some6 = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
var some1 = some2 = some3 = false;
var some4 = some5 = some6 = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

`var some1 = some2 = some3 = false, some4, some5, some6;`

Since the last 3 variables are `null`, you can implicitly set them as `null` by not assigning them to anything.

Comment: Not correct: you don't set them implicitly to `null`, but to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Err, you could use arrays.

```
var somes = [false, false, false, null, null, null];
alert(somes[0]); //Alerts 'false'
alert(somes[3]); //Alerts 'undefined'
```

Is that what you are looking for?